# how to resolve the situation if email does not received?

Tags: php, html

I wrote a code using php, html and css. This an contact form that is received by an email after submission. There is no error while submitting but i am not getting the email. I am including the code here. This is the link: http://complaintdesk.byethost15.com/contact.php.
Also I incude the code here.

contact.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['fullname'];
    $branch = $_POST['branch'];
    $usn = $_POST['usn'];
    $sem = $_POST['sem'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $description = $_POST['comment'];

    $to = 'email@example.com';

    $display = 'From:</br>Name: $name</br>USN: $usn</br>Branch: $branch</br>Semester: $sem</br>Email: $email</br></br>$description';
    mail($to,$subject,$display);
    echo "<script>alert('Your Complaint has been succesfully submitted, We will contact you soon.')</script>";
};

?>
```

And the rest of code i am not including...

Comment: Seems like a good design.  Complaints go directly into a black hole.

Comment: `"i am not getting the email"` - There could be any number of problems between the mail server and your inbox.  Does the server actively refuse the message?  Does it silently ignore the message?  Does it fail to forward the message to your incoming mail server?  Does your incoming mail server filter the message?  Does your email client filter the message?  A ton of things can prevent you from seeing an email in your inbox, and very few of them have anything to do with your code.  When you debug this, what is the response from the SMTP server?

Comment: Check your mail logs on the outgoing server to see if it was sent, then check the mail logs on your incoming server to see if it was received. one of these will tell you what is up. Also it may help if you actually checked the return value of the mail command to see if it worked!

Comment: Avoid providing personal information in your question

Comment: Remove semi colon after closing braces or was it a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$to_address = "Your email address";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers.= "From: ".$email."\r\n";

if (mail($to_address,$subject,$description,$headers)){
    echo "Success";
}
else{
    echo "<h2>Unable to submit the form, please recheck the details.</h2>" ;
 }
```

Update: If this does not work then there might be an error with your email configuration. As suggested by other users in the comments above, you might want to look into that part too. This answer is based on assumption that your email server/PHP is configured correctly.

Comment: The error message is a bit ambiguous as it is unlikely to fail based on form fields, but yes if it returns a value for success / failure like mail does, then you should always check it.